# Add alarm project into a react native expo

Tags: react-native, expo

How do I use this project https://github.com/vasyl91/react-native-android-alarms in an expo project?

The instruction mention an android folder but in my expo project I didn't see any android folder.

Comment: I think the "android" folder is the one that you can find in the package downlaoaded from the github website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use this module, you must eject to the Expo. You can't just use it. You can eject with this command.

You can run this code . `expo eject`